# what is the error in my android application?

Tags: android

Your project contains error(s), please fix them before running your application , i have this error message when running my application m with the red (x) mark on the project folder andi don't know where the error is (in which file ?? )

can you help me ??!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes when I start working on a new XML layout file, something that Eclipse sees before I get all the starting and ending tags in place causes it to flag an error that it never clears. As you found, manually clearing the error takes care of it.

Answer (score 1):

If none of the java source code files contains error the error resides in one of the other project files (well, d'uh...)

Easy solution, works 90% of the cases: mark your project and select "Clean..." from the Project menu.
If that does not helt check you project's build path. 
Then examine your manifest and xml files.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes when I delete some files in `res/drawable` folder, I have an x-mark on my project without anything wrong with other files. So I went to "`Project > Clean` " and mark my project to clean all problem. That solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are running in eclipse.. Take a look at the "problems" view.  You should see the offending error at the top.  If it is something generic regarding a gen folder, just delete the error (right click delete) and try to build again.  You can also try to do a clean build.

Comment: yes you are great, i've cleaded it and rebuild it and everything going well thanks alot